# Saving data from 1 cell to the next in Jupyter notebook

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

[image]

I'm working in a Jupyter notebook. I want to open a kml file in 1 cell and do some analysis in the next. After selecting a file , the first cell has:

```
# Print the selected path, filename, or both
print(fc.selected_path)
print(fc.selected_filename)
print(fc.selected)
global mytext 
with open(fc.selected, 'r') as f:
    print(f.read())
    mytext = f.read()
```

This prints out the contents of the file as expected.

In the next cell , I try to print out my text , but I get an empty string.

How do I pass the contents of the file to the my text variable in the next cell?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`f.read()` exhausts a file and leaves the cursor at the end of the file, therefore `mytext` doesn't receive any more content.

Try reading first and then printing:

```
with open(fc.selected, 'r') as f:
    mytext = f.read()
    print(mytext)
```